Need a DAX formula for finding count of servers of Table1 which are missing from Table2, Table3, table4
All 4 tables are connected through index column
Table1 is VM having Colm  Server_name
Table2 is Tool having  Colm  Server_name
Table3 is Excluded having  Colm Server_name,Tool_Name
Table4 is Active having  Colm  Server_name,Tool_Name
I want count of server names of VM table which are not present in any three tables which are Tool, Excluded, Activeusing DAX formula.
From Excluded and Active table I only want values to be searched which have "D" as value in Tool_Name column.
tried dax formulas from Chat gpt and all but showing parameter unexpected and Cant find values errors

You can create new tables that only include rows from Excluded and Active where Tool_Name = "D" :
Excluded_D = CALCULATETABLE (
    VALUES (Excluded[Server_name]),
    Excluded[Tool_Name] = "D"
)

Active_D = CALCULATETABLE (
    VALUES (Active[Server_name]),
    Active[Tool_Name] = "D"
)

and you can combine the server names from the 3  into one table and then extract the unique server names:
Combined_Servers = UNION (
    VALUES (Tool[Server_name]),
    Excluded_D,
    Active_D
)

and then your measure :
VM_Exclusive_Count = COUNTROWS (
    EXCEPT (
        VALUES (VM[Server_name]),
        Combined_Servers
    )
)

